# Unable to post to facebook page through cron job

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cron, facebook-php-sdk

I have followed the procedure to add post on facebook page via cron job as per below referred document. But due to some issue, I am getting below permission error at the time of running cron job even I have access of all required permission. Also I have raised bug in "facebook for developer" site. They suggested me to check with you as there is issue with the code which I have used in Graph API.

Could you please help me to add post on facebook page.

Below are the few required details.

1) Referred Document(from Step 15)

http://connectwide.com/modules/elegantalautopostallinonesocials/classes/apis/facebook/facebook_app_user_guide.pdf

2) Command of cron job which I have setup in Prestashop:

curl "http://connectwide.com/module/elegantalautopostallinonesocials/cron?id_elegantalautopostallinonesocials=6&secure_key=JP2ZHdZ7S5DJ"

3) Command used in graph API explorer:

POST▾→ /v3.2▾/"http://connectwide.com/module/elegantalautopostallinonesocials/cron?id_elegantalautopostallinonesocials=6&secure_key=JP2ZHdZ7S5DJ"

4) Error on Graph API:

{
"error": {
"message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: "http:",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 803,
"fbtrace_id": "DPaXSpYtrvF"
}
}

5) Backend Error on running cron job:

(#200) If posting to a page, \ requires both manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with \ sufficient administrative permission

6) Session URL:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/654064421706555/?session_id=786683628398161

Expected Result: I expect that post will be added on facebook page automatically through the cron job

Comment: please search StackOverflow by "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist"

Comment: Hi Syed, I have checked and tried in multiple ways but no luck. Please suggest what need to chang in Graph API command

Comment: Can you update the session url? It does not exist

Comment: Did you make sure your Access Token is linked to an admin account on this FB Page? Otherwise manage_pages and publish_pages permissions won't be enough. Also, I wouldn't post these tokens in clear... you might want to edit your post.

Comment: tokens are meant to be kept secret. never ever post them. you need to invalidate them now, because even if you edit the post, they will be in the history. it´s like leaving your house key in front of the house, where everyone can see it.

Comment: btw, i see app secrets in the screenshots too, those are also meant to be kept secret, as the name suggests ;)

Comment: Hi Bizmate, Please find new session url. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/654064421706555/?session_id=786683628398161

Comment: Hi @BrunoLeveque, I have added access token and page access token in Prestashop. Could you please let me know how can I linked an admin account on this FB Page.

Comment: @GauravShivhareDrmzEvolve, sure, follow these steps: Click Settings at the top of your Page. Click Page Roles in the left column. Type a name or email in the box and select the person from the list that appears. Click Editor to select a role from the dropdown menu. Click Add and enter your password to confirm. I hope this helps.

Comment: @BrunoLeveque, I have added earlier my name and facebook page as admin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a **Page Token** of that Page with the `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permissions. Make sure you are not using a User Token.

Also, make sure to use **Extended Tokens**. You can debug your Tokens here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Last but not least: Try it with the App in development mode, not live mode. You have to go through a review process nowadays for publishing posts to a Page, if you put it live.

More information about Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: Hello, I am using Page token of that page and it has all the required access which is mentioned in referred document. Also I am working in development mode. Can you please confirm if I am using the correct command in graph API.

Comment: links number 2 and 3 do not work for me. i suggest adding screenshots to stackoverflow, it´s a bad idea to upload them to some external resource.

Comment: How can I send you code. Can you please give me your email id,so I can send the details to you in email.

Comment: How Can I send you code. Could you please share your email id so I can send the details through mail.

Comment: please add code to your question here on stackoverflow. only the relevant parts, of course.

Comment: It is already mentioned in question. 1) Command of cron job which I have setup in Prestashop:

curl "http://connectwide.com/module/elegantalautopostallinonesocials/cron?id_elegantalautopostallinonesocials=6&secure_key=JP2ZHdZ7S5DJ"

2) Command used in graph API explorer:

POST▾→ /v3.2▾/"http://connectwide.com/module/elegantalautopostallinonesocials/cron?id_elegantalautopostallinonesocials=6&secure_key=JP2ZHdZ7S5DJ"

Comment: number 2 does not work for me, as i said. white page. again, you really should post api calls and code directly on stackoverflow, not on external resources. they may be offline in a few months or years and this thread becomes pointless.